# How can i do layout with auto creating and resizing Image Views

Tags: java, android, image, layout, view

I need to create a layout with auto re-scaled image views, but I don't know how.
I have a sample fill_parent layout, 200dp. How can I add five or six or ten, etc. image views to this layout? 
I'd appreciate any help.

[image: first image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`adjustViewBounds` is the parameter for preserving aspect ratio.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    ...
```

You can put the `ImageView`s in just about any container, but what I've found is that the trick to making `adjustViewBounds="true"` work is that one dimension should be fixed (i.e. "match_parent", or say "320dp") and that the other dimension should be variable (i.e. "wrap_content").

Comment: I need to add this image views to linear layout?

Comment: LinearLayout is a good choice.  If you have more images than can fit on the screen, use a LinearLayout with orientation="vertical" and put that inside a ScrollView.